# I need some help finding a second solution to $t^2 y''-2ty=3t^2-1$ given the fact that $y_1=t^{-1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

Using the fact that $y_1$=$t^{-1}$ then $y_2$= z $\cdot$ $t^{-1}$

$y_2'= z'\cdot t^{-1} - z \cdot t^{-2}$

$y_2''= z''\cdot t^{-1} - z'\cdot t^{-2}  - z'\cdot t^{-2}  + 2 \cdot z \cdot t^{-3}$

Substituting into the original equation:

$t^2  (z''\cdot t^{-1} - z'\cdot t^{-2} - z'\cdot t^{-2} + 2\cdot z \cdot t^{-3})-2t(z \cdot t^{-1})$

Which I then simplified into:

$t\cdot z''-4\cdot z'+2z\cdot t^{-1} -2z = 3 t^2 -1$

I want to use the method of reduction of order to find the second solution, by setting $w=z'$, but there are too many orders of $z$ remaining in the equation. Not sure where I keep going wrong!

Comment: This equation can not be solved using the known elementary functions

Comment: There is a typo in the problem definition.

Comment: @mamar Your equation hasn't solution and $y_1$ doesn't satisfy it as well.

Answer (score 1):

If $y_1=t^{-1}$ is to be a solution of the homogeneous equation with minimal changes to the given equation, then the equation has to read
$$
t^2y''-2y=3t^2-1.
$$
Then the homogeneous equation is Euler-Cauchy with characteristic polynomial $0=m(m-1)-2=(m-2)(m+1)$. Thus the second basis solution is $y_2=t^2$.

Then a particular solution can be found in the form $y_0=A\ln(t)t^2+B$.